# Display Jstree Attributes on the Right Side

Tags: javascript, jstree

I'm working on Jstree And I want to display a Node attribute on full right side of the screen. [Css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exYsV.png)
[Currently Showing Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZEva.png)
[I want to show the attribute like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCIZi.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can get that by using "wholerow" plugin and a little html/css in jstree nodes. Below is a working example without your icons.

```js
var rawData = [
    {id: "1", parent: "#", label: "Main Item", amount: 10},
    {id: "1.1", parent: "1", label: "Child Item", amount: 4},
    {id: "1.1.1", parent: "1.1", label: "Sub Child Item", amount: 4},
    {id: "1.2", parent: "1", label: "Child Item 1", amount: 2},
    {id: "1.2.1", parent: "1.2", label: "CHeckkkk", amount: 2},
    {id: "1.3", parent: "1", label: "Child Item 2", amount: 2},
    {id: "1.4", parent: "1", label: "Child Item 3", amount: 2},
    {id: "1.5", parent: "1", label: "New Node 176", amount: 0},
    {id: "2", parent: "#", label: "New Node", amount: 0},
    {id: "3", parent: "#", label: "New Node 173", amount: 0},
    {id: "4", parent: "#", label: "New Node 175", amount: 0}
];

rawData.forEach((e, i) => e.text = `${e.label}<span class='amount'>${e.amount}</span>`);

$('#jstree').jstree({
    core: {
      data: rawData
    },
    plugins: ['wholerow']
  })
  .on('loaded.jstree', function() {
    $('#jstree').jstree('open_all');
  });
```

```css
#jstree-container {
  width: 300px;
}

li.jstree-node a {
  width: 100%;
}

span.amount {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.12/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.12/jstree.min.js"></script>

<div id="jstree-container">
  <div id="jstree"></div>
</div>
```